# Including libraries in c++ form

Tags: c++, c

I have been making console applications in c++ forever. Now i want to switch over to making forms. So I was just wondering how I would include other libaries. For example I wanted to make a program that had a function involving time, in a console app i would put #include .... I want to know what is the equivlance of this in a form. By the way, im using visual c++ 2010 for windows

Comment: what "forms" do you mean? windows forms?

Comment: It's the same as in console apps

Comment: The problem with not including an example of your attempts or code is that we have no idea what you are talking about. If you are using Forms with C++ or Forms with C, then the answer is "it works the same way" but it sounds like maybe you have used forms with C# or XAML, in which case the answer is: tell us what you are using first.

Comment: -1 but I think you're looking for Qt, wxwindows, gtk++ and similar (I'm not that well versed with them)

Answer (score 0):

exactly the same way. Gui application is not any kind of magic, it just provides graphical interface in addition to what you have done in your ordinary code (for console application i.e)
Ofcourse the correct answer depends also on particular type of framework that you use, it may put some constraints.

Comment: Except when it is -- e.g. if you choose the right options to create .NET based forms where any code you write is essentially C# scripting into a very large run time :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your have static libraries, right? just include the headers as usual and the your Form project the path for libraries and link them.